# Best way to store array of consts

Tags: assembly

I'm new in asm (masm 64bit).
In my program i need an array of 64bit constants (30 constants) so that i'll be able to get them by offset from first constant.
What is the best way to do it?
Stack, directly move via mov(i'm not sute that i can move contants to memory without registers) or smth else?
thanks in advance

Comment: On what platform? Which assembler? etc? It matters. You can probably just put those constants in memory with *zero instructions*, but the syntax will depend on the answer you give to "which assembler".

Comment: sorry, forgot about it. i've edited post

Answer (score 0):

Because of the 'mov', I suspect you are talking about x86 assembler, you should specify that!

If they are really constants (i.e. they don't vary, an are known at compile time) there is
no reason to store them in memory. You can declare them as 'equ's and just use them in
your code.

If you have to index them at run-time, you can use the BasePointer, or Source Index to point at the base of
the table, and then use offsets to retrieve the values. In one instruction, you can specify a constant offset,
or use another register to add to the base.

Have a look at this page:

http://www.supernovah.com/Tutorials/Assembly3.php

It has many examples.